# Trying to learn input-output formalism: 2-photon Fock state entering a cavity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, cavity-qed

I really don't understand the input-output formalism. I've gone through the 1985 [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3761), and I get completely lost when the following formula is written:

$$b_{out}(t)-b_{in}(t) = \sqrt{\gamma} c(t)$$

To quote the paper:

> "We *specify* the input $b_{in}$ and solve 2.12 [the quantum langevian
> equation], for a(t). We then compute the output from the known a(t)
> and $b_{in}$ by use of the boundary condition, 2.22 [the above
> equation]. "

The quantum langevian equation is:
\begin{aligned}
\dot{a}=-\frac{1}{\hbar}\left[a, H_{\text {sys }}\right]-[ & {\left[a, c^{\dagger}\right]\left(\frac{\gamma}{2} c+\sqrt{\gamma} b_{\text {in }}(t)\right] } \\
& \left.-\left(\frac{\gamma}{2} c^{\dagger}+\sqrt{\gamma} b_{\text {in }}^{\dagger}(t)\right)[a, c]\right]
\end{aligned}

So how do I actually work with this formalism in real-life situations?

Here are two examples that I think would be helpful:

1. A single photon with a bandwidth of $g(\omega)$ enters an empty optical cavity. What comes out of both sides of the cavity (transmitted and reflected)? You can make $g(\omega)$ any function, such as a gaussian or lorentzian, if that makes the problem easier.
2. A 2-photon Fock state $|2\rangle$ with bandwidth of $g(\omega)$ enters an empty optical cavity. What comes out?

Comment: "I've gone through the 1985 paper" - which paper?

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3761

Comment: The problem posed is too generic to be solvable. What are the commutator relations of $a$, $b$ and $c$? (Presumably all bosonic?) Which spaces do they live in? (Presumably $a$ and $c$ both live on the space of the system?) What is $H_{sys}$?

Comment: @Wolpertinger, I'm looking for a simple calculation of an empty cavity that has a 2-photon Fock state entering it. I am asking how one would pose this question in the context of the input-output formalism. My question is asking how to apply these standard formulas to this problem.

Comment: So I would say that $H_sys$ is just the hamiltonian for the efield in a cavity and the coupling of the bath modes. a, b, and c, are just arbitrary operators.

Answer (score 0):

The central point to note is that input-output theory is not always easy practically. In particular, one cannot straightforwardly specify the full quantum state because the equations are in the Heisenberg picture. In addition, one often requires further assumptions, such as that the system and environment are initially uncorrelated. The beauty of input-output is that there are very few such assumptions (mostly Markov in the given formulation) intrinsically, making it very general. However, this comes at the cost of not being solvable direct.

Let us therefore consider a special case. For the example, I will assume that $c=a$ and a simple cavity system Hamiltonian $H_\mathrm{sys}=\hbar\omega_c a^\dagger a$. We then have (up to signs and factors of i, some of which are also missing in the OP).

$$\dot{a} = -i\omega_c a - \frac{\gamma}{2} a - \sqrt{\gamma} b_\mathrm{in}(t) \,.$$

What do we do with this equation? As mentioned, the problem is that we cannot easily compute a density matrix or quantum state since it is in the Heisenberg picture. However, we can compute expectation values! E.g. if you want something like the expectation value of the electric field, you need observables such as $\langle a \rangle$. Taking expectation values on both sides in the above equation gives.

$$\langle \dot{a} \rangle = -\left(i\omega_c + \frac{\gamma}{2}\right) \langle a \rangle - \sqrt{\gamma} \langle b_\mathrm{in}(t) \rangle \,.$$

So if you know the expectation value of the input field, you can straightforwardly solve this linear differential equation to get the result (e.g. by taking the Fourier transform, the problem can be easily solved in the frequency domain).

One can proceed similarly to derive equations for higher-order expectation values such as $\langle a^\dagger a \rangle$ if one is interested in photon counting. However, also for other cases of $c$, the equations may not be straightforwardly linear and one requires additional assumptions such as a factorized input state between the bath and system.

For a two-photon wave packet, for example, it already becomes quite complicated if the problem is nonlinear (see e.g. [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.91.043845) paper). For an empty cavity, the problem is usually linear and therefore exactly solvable. Actually input-output theory is somewhat of an overkill in that case and unnecessarily complicates the situation. I would just use standard scattering theory in that case (see e.g. [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.43.467) standard reference and [this](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.10.011008) paper for the connection to input-output).