It doesn't seem like energy is conserved for "input-output theory" of a cavity
For a long time I have struggled to make sense of "input-output theory."
And unfortunately, I still cannot make any intuitive sense out of it.
The key equation (found in this famous resource) is this boundary condition
$$
\alpha_\text{out}(t) = \alpha_\text{in}(t) - \sqrt{\kappa}\alpha(t)
\, ,
$$
but immediately, this is already unclear. If for example I have a one-sided cavity that sends light into a cavity, then this suggests that what I get is a linear combination of the light that has originally entered, and destructive interference of the light in the mode of the cavity.
What this actually physically represents is not clear to me. What I would expect would be linear interference of light that was rejected from the cavity, interfering with the light that is leaking from the cavity.
$$a_{out} = R(a_{in}) a_{in}(t) +  \sqrt{\kappa} a_{cavity}(t).$$
Something like this would be more sensible. $R(a_{in})$ is the reflection coefficienct of transmission function of the cavity, which is dependent on the input frequency of the light. And this interferes with some leackage light, which has some amplitude and phase.
So how exactly do I make physical sense of this weird form for the boundary condition. It has been for a long time really unclear to me what this actually represents.

Can you please provide a reference for this "input-output theory"? You need a unitary process.

I have provided a link. Also I agree that this lack of unitarity makes no sense to me, and is the primary source of my confusion.

the link is under pay-wall. So, whatever that equation means and just as an intuition, I'd expect "useful out" to be less than "in" in a physical system, so the minus sign looks fine to me.

Cannot download the paper you reference. You can try to model the "in-out" system with a beamsplitter, which is described by a unitary operation.

@flippiefanus, a cavity involves multiple passes that are constructively interfering. My question is that I would think that if you were going to dumb-down the cavity part to be a single linear mode that is leaking out, then you would expect that it would look like a unitary beam splitter operation. YET, the standard formalism does not seem to have things normalized in a way that makes sense...

You question is not clear. The reference is behind a pay wall. So I strongly suggest that you clearly describe the system (what is a "one-sided cavity"?) with a figure, if possible, and also give a clear definition of what input-output theory is. If I have a better understanding of what your system looks like I may be able to suggest how to model it in a unitary fashion so that all the multiple reflections are taken into account.

@flippiefanus, see this question for a more detailed example question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/805204/trying-to-learn-input-output-formalism-2-photon-fock-state-entering-a-cavity

A "one sided cavity" is a situation in which light is trapped by 2 mirrors. One mirror is perfectly reflective, and the other has reflection R. As a result, standing wave modes get trapped inside the cavity. Now you take your system with hamiltonian H, and you put it in between these two mirrors. This paper supposedly works out how to solve it. It is commonly used in academic papers. Yet no one, has been able to explain to me what it is exactly or how it works.

The characteristics of the cavity make a big difference.  The temperature of a black body cavity for instance results in a spread of energy across a spectrum that to a large part is determined by the degeneracy of each mode.  The coupling to the cavity is also important.  Check out Einstein A and B Coefficients for more information.  If you like that answer let me know before I post it to your question.

A real optical cavity is many things, but it is not a unitary system. We can make the choice of approximating it with a unitary system, but the word "damped" in that paper title indicates to me that the authors are not interested in that idealization.

If it is damped then there is loss in the system. One can also model loss with the aid of a beamsplitter where one of the output ports is traced out.

The reflection properties of the cavity are contained in the input-output formula via the mode parameters. Or rather, the input-output approach models the reflection coefficient as a sum of Lorentzians.
For the single mode case in the OP, the evolution of the mode comes out as
$$\dot{a}(t) = (i\omega_c-\kappa) a(t) + \sqrt{\kappa} a_{in}(t)$$
(for the case where the input/output channel is also the only leakage channel). The first term here is the free evolution of the mode according to its corresponding Master equation and the second term the driving from the external input mode.
Fourier transforming this relation gives in the frequency domain
$$a(\omega) = \frac{\sqrt{\kappa} a_{in}(\omega)}{i(\omega-\omega_0)+\kappa}$$
and similarly for the input-output equation
$$a_{out}(\omega) = a_{in}(\omega) - \sqrt{\kappa} a(\omega) \,.$$
Together, that is substituting the Master equation solution into the input-output relation, we get
$$a_{out}(\omega) = \left[1 -  \frac{\sqrt{\kappa}}{i(\omega-\omega_0)+\kappa} \right] a_{in}(\omega) = R(\omega) a_{in}(\omega) \,.$$
This is something of the form the OP is looking for. The reflection coefficient therefore comes out of solving the Master equation and input-output relation as coupled equations. It does not have to be put in as an extra ingredient.
What one is effectively doing here is that one is decomposing the cavity response into modes (above a single mode). One can prove in general that input-output theory exactly reproduces scattering theory if certain modifications are included, see this paper.
(Disclaimer: there are probably some wrong signs and $i$ factors here...)

While an explicit calculation of this simple case is appreciated. This question is asking how the input-output equation makes any sense. This equation does not appear to be unitary and it's not clear where it even comes from.
I understand the method to get a solution for the output is to simply plug things in, but from a physical standpoint it's really unclear what's going on.

Dear Steven, thanks for the feedback. I'm afraid I don't quite understand the question then. My answer intended to show why the input-output form that you would find more intuitive sort of double-counts the reflection. With regards to the remaining question, I'll have to pass. I would recommend to have a look at the linked paper though, maybe this can help.

In a related practical experiment one can place a mirror at the output of a laser ... effectively the energy of the laser has no where to go/dissipate. We can say there is destructive interference of the field BUT not of the energy!  In practice the laser will stop lasing, energy consumption is reduced to near zero.   How far one can place this mirror from the source would depend on beam quality/coherence etc.  The laser can also get damaged in such an experiment, in multimode laser diodes a few modes may be able to escape ... all lasing energy will tend to dump there, which can damage the crystal or exit mirror.  I would think this effect would be true even for an optical cavity ... an optical cavity after a laser beam can improve beam quality.  In all these cases it is the EM field that extends from the laser into the cavity that is responsible (not the energy).

An interesting comment, but I'm not sure this is an answer to the question. Also, it's not super clear to me what exactly is happening in the situation you describe. I get the general idea of making an off-resonant cavity using a single mirror and the cavity. I guess you're saying that this create some kind of anti-Purcell effect that rejects that frequency, but in the end this just cause more unusual frequencies to get lased instead which can cause damage to things? I wouldn't have thought that you'd get this kind of anti-Purcell effect unless the light is in a loop interacting with the gain

With the gain medium. That is that the mirror is actively enabling or preventing the stimulated emission in the lasing process.

Purcell is for spontaneous emission ... but lasers are stimulated emission.  But yes anti-Purcell, the optical cavity outside the laser could enhance or de-enhance desired frequencies.  The damage I refer to in the laser diode in simply the concentration of electric current in the crystal which gives concentrated emissions in the exit mirror, modes find the best geometry.... ideally the diode should be unhindered uniform.

My understanding is based on the EM field ... the field becomes extended to include proximal optical components. The medium/air path/optical cavity all share a common EM field.  The EM field is the loop ... and it extends further than the typical scientist would expect.

OK, let's consider a one-sided cavity, which is given by a semi-transparent mirror and a fully reflective mirror at some distance behind the first. Such a system can be modeled with beamsplitter representing the two input ports as the opposite sides of the first mirror and the one output port of the beamsplitter directed back to one of the input ports with some phase delay. (If I have time, I draw some figures to add here).
What complicates the calculation is the implied feedback. If the initial state is parameterized by a single parameter function (such as a single photon state or a coherent state), one can perform the calculation of the parameter function for the output state in the same way one would calculate it for a classical field in this scenario. So, let's consider the classical case. Here one would solve it by setting up self-consistent equations where one of the outputs is equal to one of the inputs. It can be represented in matrix form as
$$ \left[\begin{array}{c}f_{\text{out}} \\ f_{\text{cav}}\end{array}\right] 
= \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \Phi \end{array}\right] 
\left[\begin{array}{cc} C & -iS \\ -iS & C \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}f_{\text{in}} \\ f_{\text{cav}} \end{array}\right] . $$
All the functions are spectral functions. The first matrix one the right introduces the propagation delay with transfer function $\Phi$ and the second matrix is the beamsplitter (or mirror) with $C=S=1/\sqrt{2}$ for a 50:50 beamsplitter. After multiplying out the matrices, one gets two equations, leading to a relationship between the input and output fields after eliminating the cavity field:
$$ f_{\text{out}} = \frac{C-\Phi}{1-\Phi C} f_{\text{in}} . $$
If the initial state cannot be represented by a single parameter function (as for example with squeezed states and thermal states), one needs a more general approach. I've seen some people using ladder operators in the way one would use the parameter functions to come up with some way to address such situations. What it basically comes down to is a phase space-like approach where the ladder operators double for phase space variables.
Let's then do this on phase space in a formally justifiable way. (There is a formal one-to-one relationship between operators on Hilbert space and Wigner functions on phase space.) If we are only interested in the particle number degrees of freedom, the state can be represented as a Wigner function $W(\alpha)$ on a two-dimensional phase space with $\alpha$ as complex variable. However, for the current system that would be trivial because particles are not created or destroyed here. So, we are also interest in the other degrees of freedom (the spatiotemporal degrees of freedom). Then the state is represented by a Wigner functional $W[\alpha]$ and the phase space becomes a functional phase space with $\alpha(\mathbf{k})$ being a field variable. Now the effect of the beamsplitter and the phase delay gives a transformation on the field variables:
$$ \alpha \rightarrow C\mu +i S\nu $$
and
$$ \nu \rightarrow \Phi C\nu +i \Phi S\mu $$
where $\nu$ is the field variable for the cavity and $\mu$ is the field variable for the output state. Note that the signs are different because field variables transform with the opposite signs compared to parameter functions. Or wth the Hermitian adjoint of the unitary operations. When we again eliminate the cavity field variables, we get the output state in terms of the input state with the field variable transformation:
$$ \mu = \frac{C-\Phi^*}{1-\Phi^* C} \alpha . $$
Hope this helps.

A unique looking take on the matter. Thank you. Although I can't quite follow some parts of it. For example is this "relationship between the input and output fields" unitary? Also This second part about a "formally justifiable way" isn't very clear to me.
Also furthermore, I am unfortuantely interested in other properties like squeezing, although even a single parameter, "classical" estimate, would be helpful for my understanding.

For squeezing you need a nonlinear process. This is a linear system. So it won't give you squeezing.

For this "input-output" system methodology, it is meant to work out more generally how a cavity system (with a Hamiltonian that includes a single quantized field) interacts with a free-field (continuous field) that is being sent into the system as an input.
